# How do I modify my code to use strtol() instead of scanf() to read in first two ints only?

Tags: c, matrix, int, scanf, strtol

My current code seems to work fine on DOS but not on Unix, and I need to make it work on both. From what I have found so far, it seems I should use strtol(). However, I cannot seem to figure out how to get strtol() to get only the first two integers.

The input is a text file that looks like this:

```
45x7
(1,0)
(10,2)
```

And I need the output to be "There are 45 rows and 7 columns."

This is my current code:

```
int rows=0, columns=0;
scanf("%d%*c%d%*c", &rows, &columns);
printf("There are %d rows and %d columns.", rows, columns);
return 0;
```

I do not want to discard the remaining text file as I will need to process that as well.

Comment: `not on Unix` - how does it "not work"? `my current code` - you are missing `int main() {` and `#include <stdio.h>` and `}`. After I fix your code, I get exactly the output you specified for the input you specified.

Comment: Append `\n` to the `printf`.

Comment: Running your code on Linux (Mint 19) works OK. Is it possible input file has BOM, Unicode or similar ?

Comment: Presumably the `"%d%*c%d%*c"` in your `scanf` call is supposed to read an int, skip the `x`, read another int, and skip the `\n`.  If anything I'd expect this to have more problems under DOS or Windows (where lines are terminated with `\r\n`, although in text mode this wouldn't matter).  In any case, you might consider other techniques.  My first suggestions would be `%dx%d` to explicitly match the `x`, and a check on `scanf`'s return value to make sure it's 2.

Comment: Many people (myself included) recommend avoiding `scanf`, and `strtol` is often part of the alternative -- but only part.  The first step is usually to read exactly one *line* of text, using `fgets` or the like. Then, you can either (a) parse the line by calling `sscanf`, or (b1) break the line up into "fields" by calling `strtol` or the like (here with a delimiter of `'x'`) and (b2) call something like `strtol` on each field, or (c) use various other ad-hoc parsing techniques.

Comment: Another possibility would be to call `strtol` on the while line to get `rows`, look at the returned end pointer to see if it points to an `'x'`, increment the pointer, and call `strtol` again to get `columns`.

Comment: But your code works perfectly, as-is, for me, too, under MacOS, which is enough like Unix these days that it's a useful test.  So there's something else going on for you, that we can't see, and it would be good to figure that out.

Comment: @SteveSummit I did attempt to use fgets() to read in a line, then tried strtol() twice on the line. The problem I found was that it would only read the first integer twice, ignoring the second completely. How would you suggest implementing it in a way that I can set the delimiter to 'x'?

Comment: To everyone saying it works on their Unix, that just puzzles me even more.. I believe the output I got was "There are 4 rows and . columns." Not 100% sure thats exact and I don't have access to a unix shell at this moment; but it was definitely messed up like that. I put it down to scanf being unreliable between the two systems.. I am not sure what else to say on that other than maybe somewhere else in my code characters are being consumed ? That would be weird though, as this is the first thing in my main function that happens.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of using `fgets` and `strtol`.  It is admittedly more verbose than the `scanf` solution.

```
int rows=0, columns=0;
char *endp;
char firstline[100];
if(fgets(firstline, sizeof(firstline), stdin) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "premature EOF\n");
    exit(1);
}
rows = strtol(firstline, &endp, 10);
if(*endp != 'x') {
    fprintf(stderr, "syntax error\n");
    exit(1);
}
columns = strtol(endp + 1, &endp, 10);
if(*endp != '\n') {
    fprintf(stderr, "syntax error\n");
    exit(1);
}
printf("There are %d rows and %d columns.\n", rows, columns);
```

The key is that `strtol`'s second argument is a *pointer to a pointer* which is filled in with a pointer to the first character `strtol` didn't use.  That is, when you pass the string `45x7\n` to the first `strtol` call, it returns `45`, and sets `endp` to point to the `x`.